# Avalonia MVVM: splitting large xaml files

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, avaloniaui

I am using Avalonia UI to develop a rather large single-window application using a `Carousel` control to switch between pages. As to be expected my `MainWindow.xaml` file is getting pretty large. It's currently at about 600 lines of code with only a fraction of the UI finished and I figured it's time to refactor. I have already used `UserControl`s where ever redundant code was present.

So I was wondering: **What would be the best way to shrink the size of my main window xaml file?**

As I am using the MVVM version of Avalonia (I think there is another project template, correct me if I am wrong) I also have to worry about how to deal with all the bindings to my `MainWindowViewModel.cs` (which I cleaned up by making the class partial and splitting it into several files, each holding the code for one of my `Carousel` tabs).

My current plan is to outsource every `Carousel` page into a separate `UserControl` and then somehow pass references to the parent `Carousel` via bindings and Avalonia properties to be able to switch between pages from my backend and hopefully find a way to do this while complying to the principles of MVVM and without messing up all the bindings.

I am sure this will create new problems on it's own though and would be rather painful to rewrite so I figured I am probably not the first person to use Avalonia in a somewhat big project. So is there a better alternative to my approach?

I heard of `StyleInclude` but was unable to find comprehensive documentation of what it does, how it works and when it should be used.

Comment: Couldn't you just have a currrentViewModel in your MainWindowViewModel and then assign the currentViewModel to the ViewModle you want to display when the user clicks a button?

Comment: Good point but I'm not sure this would work for completely different xaml code?